# Determining minx/miny/maxx/maxy for shape from polygon in GeoJSON file

Tags: geopandas, shapely, fiona, mysql, serialize

I have implemented the following code to search a GeoJSON file for a point (not asking for a code review or critique):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.11
import os
import sys
import fiona
import shapely

def usage():
    print("Usage:", prog, "<shapefile> <latitude> <longitude> <tag> [<matchlimit>]", file=sys.stderr)
    return

prog=os.path.basename(__file__)

if (len(sys.argv) != 5) and (len(sys.argv) != 6):
    usage()
    sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv) == 6:
    if str.isnumeric(sys.argv[5]):
        matchlimit=int(sys.argv[5])
    else:
        usage()
        sys.exit()
else:
    matchlimit=1

matchcount=0
with fiona.open(sys.argv[1]) as fiona_collection:

    #
    # The point of interest
    #
    point = shapely.geometry.Point(sys.argv[3], sys.argv[2]) # longitude, latitude

    #
    # Iterate through the fiona collection
    #
    for shapefile_record in fiona_collection:

        #
        # Use Shapely to create the polygon
        #
        shape = shapely.geometry.shape( shapefile_record['geometry'] )

        #
        # Is the point within the polygon?
        #
        if shape.contains(point):

            #
            # Loop through argv[4] looking for keys separated by a comma.
            # Load result with values separated by a comma.
            #
            arg=sys.argv[4]
            result=""
            while (len(arg) > 0):
                i=arg.find(',')
                if i >= 0:
                    key=arg[:i]
                    arg=arg[i+1:]
                else:
                    key=arg
                    arg=""

                value=shapefile_record['properties'][key]
                if len(result) == 0:
                    result = value
                else:
                    result = result + ',' + value

            print(result)
            matchcount+=1
            if matchcount != matchlimit:
                continue

            sys.exit(0)
            break

    #
    # Didn't find a match!
    #
    sys.exit(1)
```

As I iterate through the GeoJSON file as a fiona_collection of shapefile_records, which are converted to shapes, how do I get the minx/maxx/minx/miny for the shape?

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to use shape.bounds to find the minx, miny, maxx, maxy.

Answer (score 2):

I used shape.bounds to access the tuple representing the min/max x/y, very easy:

```
minmax=(shape.bounds[0],shape.bounds[1],shape.bounds[2],shape.bounds[3])
```

Comment: Accept your own answer with the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You could get all of the vertices of each shape.

```
xx, yy = poly.exterior.coords.xy

# Note above return values are of type `array.array` 
assert x == xx.tolist()
assert y == yy.tolist()
zipped_list = list(zip(x, y))

# Convert the zipped list to a numpy array
numpy_array = np.array(zipped_list)
```

Then get the max and min of the array.

```
import numpy as np
min_values = np.min(numpy_array, axis=0)
max_values = np.max(numpy_array, axis=0)
print("Min values:", min_values)
print("Max values:", max_values)
```